# Worpdress meta query not working if value is array of strings

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i'm facing wordpress meta_query problem, from this simple query i am not able to output values :

```
(
[post_type] => offres
[meta_query] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => topics
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => PADINE
                        [1] => ALKEKENGE
                    )

                [compare] => IN
            )

    )
)
```

This is the php code :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'offres',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
             'key' => 'topics',
              'value' => array('PADINE','ALKEKENGE'),
               'compare' => 'IN'
         )
    )
);
```

On my wordpress admin i have a post assigned with 'topics' meta key and  'PADINE' as value, i wonder why is it not working ?

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Could it be typo "offres" maybe "offers" ?

Comment: Hello, post type is really 'offres'

Comment: are you sure `topics` with hold string value like _PADINE_ and _ALKEKENGE_. and are you confirm that their are offres which has the mention key with the given value?

Comment: I have a product with PADINE and another with ALKEKENGE, both have meta key 'topics' inside post type 'offres'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, it is hard to get the meta value due to the serialize structure of the data.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'offres',
    'meta_query'    => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'topics',
            'value'     => 'PADINE',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'topics',
            'value'     => 'ALKEKENGE',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        )
    )
);
```

Hope it works,

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this working, i have to do a loop to construct this array because ! have many custom fields :), thank you